# Problem to convert a SQL query to an Laravel Query Builder

Tags: sql, laravel, sqlbuilder

I want to convert this SQL Query to LAravel SQL Builder but i don't know why I already read the laravel documentation but I can't find the answer

### SQL Query:

```
SELECT
    CONTRATO,
    CASE WHEN RAZONSOCIAL IS NULL OR RAZONSOCIAL = ''
        THEN ISNULL(PATERNO, '') + ' ' + ISNULL(MATERNO, '') + ' ' + ISNULL(NOMBRES, '') 
        ELSE RAZONSOCIAL
    END AS NOMBRE,
    CADENAUNICA,
    CLAVERASTREO,
    FECHAASIENTO,
    IDGARANTIA,
    RutaGuardadoPDF,
    RutaGuardadoXML
FROM
    DEUDORES AS D
LEFT JOIN
    RELACIONES AS R
    ON D.RUGID = R.RUGID
WHERE CONTRATO = 'A1412015'
AND D.AcreedorId IN (
    SELECT
        ACREEDORID
    FROM
        [MasterCLI].[dbo].[Rrug]
    WHERE FIDEICOMISOID = 5
)
```

and i do this code in laravel

```php
$AcreedorFide = \DB::connection('sqlsrv')
    ->table('Rrug')
    ->select('AcreedorID')
    ->where('Fideicomiso', $fideicomiso)
    ->get();

$BoletaRUG = \DB::connection('RUG')
    ->table('Deudores')
    ->select(
        'Contrato',
        'CadenaUnica',
        'ClaveRastreo',
        'FechaAsiento',
        'IdGarantia',
        'RutaGuardadoPDF',
        'RutaGuardadoXML'
    )
    ->select(DB::raw('CASE WHEN RAZONSOCIAL IS NULL'))
    ->leftJoin('Relaciones','Deudores.RugId', '=', 'Relaciones.RugId')
    ->where('Contrato', $Contrato)
    ->wherein('Acreedorid', $AcreedorFide)
    ->get();
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, can you explain what is the error of your code? FYI you can get the generated SQL as string by replacing `->get()` with `->toSql()`.

Comment: i have a error in this line 
 ->select(DB::raw('CASE WHEN RAZONSOCIAL IS NULL'  )) i dont know how to make this part on angular: 

CASE WHEN RAZONSOCIAL IS NULL OR RAZONSOCIAL='' THEN ISNULL(PATERNO,'') +' '   + ISNULL(MATERNO,'') +' '+ ISNULL(NOMBRES,'') ELSE RAZONSOCIAL END AS NOMBRE

Comment: Please edit your question and add the error there, don't use comments for code. And please read [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so that someone can understand what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

The most SQL-like way of remaking this query in the Query Builder is the following:

```
DB::connection('sqlsrv')->query()
    ->select(
        'CONTRATO',
        'CADENAUNICA',
        'CLAVERASTREO',
        'FECHAASIENTO',
        'IDGARANTIA',
        'RutaGuardadoPDF',
        'RutaGuardadoXML'
    )
    ->selectRaw(
        "CASE WHEN RAZONSOCIAL IS NULL OR RAZONSOCIAL = '' ".
            "THEN ISNULL(PATERNO, '') + ' ' + ISNULL(MATERNO, '') + ' ' + ISNULL(NOMBRES, '') ". 
            "ELSE RAZONSOCIAL ".
        "END AS NOMBRE"
    )
    ->from('DEUDORES', 'D')
    ->leftJoin('RELACIONES AS R', 'D.RUGID', '=', 'R.RUGID')
    ->where('CONTRATO', '=', 'A1412015')
    ->whereIn('D.AcreedorId', function ($query) {
        $query->select('ACREEDORID')
              ->from('MasterCLI.dbo.Rrug')
              ->where('FIDEICOMISOID', '=', 5);
    })
    ->get();
```

For anyone stuck on translating queries, as the comments have stated, the easiest way to remake large, complex-looking queries in the builder is by dumping the query using `->toSql()` instead of `->get()` and checking if it's missing something or not. Trial and error.

My personal advice is to start from the subqueries and work your way up. Also, Some differences/shorthands:

- Instead of `DB::connection(...)->query()->select(...)->from('DEUDORES', 'D')->where(...)`,
  you can specify the main table you're querying first:
  `DB::connection(...)->table('DEUDORES', 'D')->select(...)->where(...)`
- If the comparison operator is `'='` you can leave it implied. In this example:

  - `leftJoin('RELACIONES AS R', 'D.RUGID', '=', 'R.RUGID')` 
    becomes `leftJoin('RELACIONES AS R', 'D.RUGID', 'R.RUGID')`
  - `where('CONTRATO', '=', 'A1412015')` becomes `where('CONTRATO', 'A1412015')`
- If you use the same connection as the default one (`DB_CONNECTION` in your `.env` file), you can skip the `connection(...)` in the queries. `DB::connection(...)->table(...)` becomes `DB::table(...)`.